# Has anyone found a working implementation of YouTube Direct?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm working on a website that has a need to accept user-submitted videos. After some research, it seemed like YouTube Direct would be a good fit for our purposes. Most Google products are very well-designed, so why should YouTube Direct be any different?

Unfortunately, I can't find a working implementation of YouTube Direct to explore. I've found several broken versions...

http://topics.gannett.com/greensboro+sit-in/?template=digtriad

http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2009/11/16/hopenhagen-ambassador-con_n_356950.html

...but they all seem to be plagued with errors.

Does anyone know of a working, error-free implementation of YouTube Direct? Is this a neglected or failed Google product? Is there a better solution to accept user video?

Thank you for any help or recommendations that come to mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out project page for [YouTube Direct Lite](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct-lite/).
There is also a [live demo](http://ytdirectlite.appspot.com/static-min/submit.html) available.